# Error handling technique for procedural hardware programming

Tags: c++, error-handling, procedural-programming

I am writing a C++ code that controls a special device that is the fusion of several SDKs.  My code looks like

```
#define sdk1SafeCall(err) __sdk1SafeCall(err,__FILE__,__LINE__)

int errorcode = 0;
sdk1SafeCall(sdk1_InitializeDevice());
errorcode=sdk2_InitializeDevice();
errorcode=sdk3_InitializeDevice();

if (some_parameter)
{
    errorcode=sdk2_readDevice(true);
}
else
{
    errorcode=sdk3_writeDevice();
}
label again: errorcode=sdk1_readDevice();
if (error) goto again;

errorcode=close_everything();
```

Use parameters will rearrange the control flow. My current method uses something like cudaSafeCall to wrap the error codes and exit. What I don't know how to do is where to store detailed explanations of these errors or how to recover from them (such as the goto example). At the end of the day the code looks really messy.

**Edit**

I do sometimes handle errors with a wrapper.

Comment: You're never actually reading the value of errorcode anyway so you could just not bother with it and achieve the same broken implementation with clearer code.

Comment: @PeteFordham I don't know what to do with them. In my actual implementation I use something like `sdk1SafeCall(sdk1_readData())` which prints a number, a `__FILE__` and a `__LINE__` like in CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing error-safe code is hard. In your pseudocode, you don't actually deal with errors at all. errorcode will just have the result of "close_everything()" - which may have succeeded, even if everything else went wrong.

The typical way to solve this sort of thing in C++ is to have an object for each "resource" (e.g. a "device"), and `throw` an `exception` if something goes wrong that you don't expect to recover from. Wrap the whole function [or an outer set of functions] in a `try/catch` block.

Of course, if "failure is normal" (e.g. you try to read from a network port, and you get a timeout because there was no data available, that's not something you should throw an exception for). This should use a return-value.

Note that using objects to handle resources requires careful design of the code and especially that your destructor does a good job of cleaning it is run after an exception. Make sure you don't leave things behind if you throw an exception in a constructor - as that is how you get leaks.

There are naturally a whole host of other solutions - after all, we're talking programming, so there's always at least 11 different ways to solve something.

Comment: What I describe above is general C++ way to do it - I don't think C++11 offers much in the way of help here - it's still a case of "If there is an error, throw an exception, and then somewhere a few call levels down, catch that exception". To explain it fully, you need many pages worth of text, and I'm sorry, but it's your task to search the web for those explanations - they are out there - or buy a book that describes how to write C++ in a safe way. If you have SPECIFIC questions, I'm happy to answer, but I'm not going to explain ALL about how to do this...

Comment: I should perhaps add that it all depends on what you want to do in case of an error - the "easy" choice is to print a message and exit. But that's not always a good alternative. If "exit and print a message" is a good choice in your case, then having a macro or function that checks for errors is another choice.

Comment: Thanks I went with using a class for the device and a macro for error checking.